# How do get the first(most recent) photo from the Photo Library in ALASSET?

Tags: ios

Is there a trick to getting the most recent photo from the iOS Photo library Programatically?

I know I can search by date, but I'd have to do scans for every microsecond in order to do some sort of comparison to find it accurately.

Has anyone done this or any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach I have taken before :

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

[group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

[group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

    if (alAsset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
        UIImage *latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];

        *stop = YES; *innerStop = YES;

    }
}];
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error : %@", [error localisedDescription]);
}];
```